# powershell newline in Send-MailMessage body

Tags: powershell

how do I get Send-MailMessage to put new lines in the body of the mail?
A separate PowerShell script generates some files, I read the content into a variable and send it as the body like so:

```
$fileContent = Get-Content -Path $file | Out-String
Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml -Body $fileContent -From $f -SmtpServer $s -To $t -Subject $s -Verbose
```

$fileContent would currently have the

```
`r`n
```

characters. When you open the file it has new lines. But when I convert to  string and send the email its all on one line. I have tried replacing like this:

```
$fileContent -replace  "`r`n","<br />"
$fileContent -replace  '`r`n','`r`n`r`n`r`n'
```

If anyone can help I would be very appreciative, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are some of the approaches you can try:

1. Using the `-BodyAsHtml` switch
2. Using the `<br />` (break) html tag

**for example:**

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Send-MailMessage -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer 'myemail.server.com' -To 'Mr To <to@server.com>' -From 'Mr From <from@server.com>' -Subject 'Powershell BodyAsHtml' -Body 'I am just adding some random words here<br />and here also Line 2.<br />And also here Line 3.<br />and one more time Line 4.<br />EOF<br />'"
```

The PowerShell newline indicator is `n (backtick-n)

Comment: Indeed you are correct, even though the answer is above in the question, I hadn't assigned the variable when I replaced the ``n` with the `<br />`. I am a dumbass. Thanks!